# Default Properties on Application_Controller for default layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view

Can I create a default property on the base Application_Controller that can be accessed in my application.html.haml view?

What I'm trying to do is show a random quote on every page of the site. I have the quotes working, no problems, but I have to set

`@quote = Quote.first(:order => "RANDOM()")`

on every method in every controller. There must be a DRYer way than that?

Cheers

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right way.

Wrap your query in a before_filter inside your ApplicationController and add in your application layout the necessary stuff to display your result.